# Actionscript (AS3) : call function only if visible

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an "intro" screen and I have a "play" screen.
As the intro screen starts it sets the play screen `visible = false;`

First the intro screen shows itself and the user has to press a button to go to the play screen, once the play screen shows itself actionscript moves a graphic from right to left.

The problem is that even when the play screen visible is false, it is still executing the actionscript (timers/enterframes etc)

is there some way to set the actionscript so that `if self.visible==false` dont play?

Please note that I am new to AS3/Flash and the code is in the movieclip itself not in a class.

Comment: What do you mean "screen"? What type of object is it?

Comment: Sorry, by screen I meant the player is first shown a movie clip called "intro" and sets the 2nd movieclip called "play" to false. This is for mobile using AIR so when I said screen, I meant the mobile screen.

Comment: Try to add the "play" to stage when needed, and call stop function of "play", remove it from stage when needn't, instead of setting visible value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do something totally automatically as you want it, you're best bet would be to extend the visible setter like so:

```
override public function set visible(value:Boolean):void
{
    if(value)
    {
        this.play();
    }
    else
    {
        this.stop();
    }
    super.visible = value;
}
```

that should go into your play screen's document class. If you're not using a document class this *might* work on the timeline.